# Any font does superscripting without requiring the inclusion of "sup" tags?

Tags: html, superscript, sup

I have a dynamic list of names which includes some superscript keywords like "®". 
I don't want to use  tag to superscript "TM" or "Registered" etc. Is there any font available which does this task without adding  tag for default keywords?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Trademark symbol (TM) which you can get by using the HTML entity `&trade;` appears like a superscript in chrome and firefox, by default.

For `&reg;` ("Registered" symbol - encircled R) I guess, it would be better to add `<sup>` tag. May be, you can run a script either on the client-side or on the server-side, to add the tags to such characters.

Comment: The `&trade;` entity denotes the ™ character and does not cause any superscripting. If the result looks superscripted, that’s because the glyph has been designed that way by the font designer (which is appropriate design).

Answer (score 0):

Many fonts contain the character “®” and especially “™” in a superscript-like appearance. It is more or less an inherent feature of these characters that they should be rendered that way. It follows that if you put them in a superscript, the result tends to be bad, especially since superscripting usually reduces font size and the size is already rather small for a poor little “R” tweaked inside a circle.

You may need to change the font of your text or, less radically, change the font for these characters. If the copy text font is a sans-serif font, consider using Lucida Sans Unicode for these characters. If serif, try Times New Roman.